# How to reserve process id in Windows

Tags: c#, windows, process, pid

I have a typical requirement that I want to run my application(C#) with same process id whenever it starts. So for this sake I want to reserve a Process ID (pid) in Windows 2003 Server Enterprise Edition so that it cannot be reused by another process by the kernel. So what changes can be made to windows registry to achieve this goal? Also I would like to know how windows assign PID to the processes running in kernel?

If this is not an optimal solution then what can be done in C#?

Comment: There's no (normal) way to do such a thing, why would you want to do this?

Comment: @Matteo There may be a probability that when my process gets terminated having a particular pid then kernel may assign that pid to another process.In the meantime if I start my process with same pid there may be an exception raised. So to avoid this condition I wanted to reserve a pid in Windows

Comment: This is clearly a case of [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What's the "bigger problem" that you are trying to solve? (also, if you need to have a "stable" reference to a process you should keep a open handle to it, not a process ID)

Comment: I wanted the same. But only for fun of it. For example why a random process should use the fancey PID of 4444 on my PC?. I wanted to reserve it for my favorite music player or the program.exe I am testing/debugging and frequently find and end that process through Task Manager.